# SSDT ODBC issue for DB2 in WINDOWS 10

Tags: ssis, db2, odbc, sql-server-data-tools

I have a `SSIS` package where I have a `ODBC` connection that runs a query in `DB2`.

When `Visual studio 2017` executes the `SSDT` package on `WINDOWS 10` it throws an error for syntactical issue. This happens on even the most simple query.

The `DB2` log notes that `"SET FMTONLY ON"` and `"SET FMTONLY OFF"` parameters are getting added automatically to the SQL query's SQL.  DB2 does not recognize the `FMTONLY` statement and throwing error.

The issue also occurs on `SSDT 2015` on `WINDOWS 10`.  However this does not occur on `WINDOWS 07` where everything is working fine. Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Are you using the same version of ODBC (32bit vs 64bit).  Are you using the same version of the driver?  I have found instances when I have had to use old drivers.

Comment: I have tried with both driver. the old one as well as the new Sybase driver for ODBC connection for DB2.

Comment: Do you have to use ODBC?  Do you have a screenshot of your connection properties or content of your SSIS package?

Comment: Yes, we have used ODBC driver. We are using Sybase driver for DSN creation.